# Changing file extensions for all files in a directory on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, file-extension

I have a directory full of files with one extension (.txt in this case) that I want to automatically convert to another extension (.md).

Is there an easy terminal one-liner I can use to convert all of the files in this directory to a different file extension?

Or do I need to write a script with a regular expression?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
for old in *.txt; do mv $old `basename $old .txt`.md; done
```

Make a copy first!

Comment: On Mavericks, this does not work for me, giving this output:  
  
    usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
           mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: just tried it on Mavericks, and it works fine.  This assumes you are using bash, the default shell.

Comment: Works fine on Mavericks, if you run into permission issues just insert sudo before the whole line, or enter a su.

Comment: This does not work for filenames with spaces in them without proper quoting.

Comment: `$old` should be enclosed in double quotes here, lest much havoc could be wreaked. Edit: The whole `\`basename ...\`` too.

Comment: With all the ways to get this wrong, I highly recommend the simple interactive [Finder solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28206204/1202830) that Vicky posted instead.

Comment: Any way of making it recursive?

Comment: @AlexandreCastro `for old in **/*.txt; do mv $old "\`dirname $old\`/\`basename $old .txt\`.md"; done`

Answer (score 84):

Alternatively, you could install the `ren` (rename) utility

```
brew install ren

ren '*.txt' '#1.md'
```

If you want to rename files with prefix or suffix in file names

```
ren 'prefix_*.txt' 'prefix_#1.md'
```

Comment: This is the best suggestion for command-line renaming of files. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to rename files with prefix or suffix in file names, you can use `ren 'prefix_*.txt' 'prefix_#1.md'`

Comment: @parliament https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935127/rename-files-recursively-mac-osx

Answer (score 49):

Terminal is not necessary for this... Just highlight all of the files you want to rename. Right click and select "Rename ## items" and just type ".txt" into to the "Find:" box and ".md" into the "Replace with:" box.

Comment: Yeah. This was great. In terminal: `open .` and then do this! Much easier.

Comment: Whoa!! Never knew about this!

Comment: Nice find, but when renaming file extensions you typically have a lot of files to process.  This method, on El Capitan, prompts you for each file asking if you really want to rename it.

Comment: I've just tried on El Capitan, and it didn't prompt me for anything. Just renamed with no questions....

Comment: Wow, that was slick.  I would recommend this over the terminal solution.

Comment: Finder > Preferences > Advanced > Show warning before changing extensions.

Comment: On Big Sur it will warn you but you can check the "apply to all files" box and it works.

Answer (score 10):

The preferred Unix way to do this (yes, OS X is based on Unix) is:

`ls | sed 's/^\(.*\)\.txt$/mv "\1.txt" "\1.md"/' | sh`

Why looping with `for` if `ls` by design loops through the whole list of filenames? You've got pipes, use them. You can create/modify not only output using commands, but also commands (right, that is commands created by a command, which is what Brian Kernighan, one of the inventors of Unix, liked most on Unix), so let's take a look what the `ls` and the `sed` produces by removing the pipe to `sh`:

```
$ ls | sed 's/^\(.*\)\.txt$/mv "\1.txt" "\1.md"/'
mv "firstfile.txt" "firstfile.md"
mv "second file.txt" "second file.md"
$
```

As you can see, it is not only an one-liner, but a complete script, which furthermore works by creating another script as output. So let's just feed the script produced by the one-liner script to `sh`, which is *the* script interpreter of OS X. Of course it works even for filenames with spaces in it.

BTW: Every time you type something in *Terminal* you create a script, even if it is only a single command with one word like `ls` or `date` etc. Everything running in a Unix shell is always a script/program, which is just some ASCII-based stream (in this case an instruction stream opposed to a data stream).

To see the actual commands being executed by `sh`, just add an `-x` option after `sh`, which turns on debugging output in the shell, so you will see every `mv` command being executed with the actual arguments passed by the `sed` editor script (yeah, another script inside the script :-) ).

However, if you like complexity, you can even use `awk` and if you like to install other programs to just do basic work, there is `ren`. I know even people who would prefer to write a 50-lines or so `perl` script for this simple every-day task.

Maybe it's easier in finder to rename files, but if connected remotely to a Mac (e.g. via `ssh`), using finder is not possible at all. That's why cmd line still is very useful.

Comment: This works nicely - to do it recursively, change 'ls' to 'find . -name "*.txt"'

Answer (score 8):

You do not need a terminal for this one; here is a sample demonstration in **MacOS Big Sur**.

- Select all the files, right-click and select `"rename..."`
  [image]
- Add the existing file extension in `"Find"` and the extension you want to replace with `"Replace with"`.
  [image]

And done!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the selected and most accurate answer above, here's a bash function for reusability:

```
function change_all_extensions() {
    for old in *."$1"; do mv $old `basename $old ."$1"`."$2"; done
}
```

Usage:

```
$ change_all_extensions txt md
```

(I couldn't figure out how to get clean code formatting in a comment on that answer.)

Answer (score 4):

No need to write a script for it just hit this command

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" | xargs -I '{}' basename '{}' | sed 's/\.txt//' | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}.txt'  '{}.md'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where files were named `.gifx.gif` at the end and this worked in OS X to remove the last `.gif`:

```
for old in *.gifx.gif; do
    mv $(echo "$old") $(echo "$old" | sed 's/x.gif//');
done
```

Comment: This will modify a few more files than you intend if they have `x?gif` anywhere in the name (for example, `maxsgift.gitx.git`). This is best: `sed s/\.gif$//'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    cd $YOUR_DIR
    ls *.txt > abc
    mkdir target // say i want to move it to another directory target in this case
    while read line
    do 
    file=$(echo $line |awk -F. '{ print $1 }')
    cp $line target/$file.md  // depends if u want  to move(mv) or copy(cp)
    done < abc
```

Answer (score 0):

list=`ls`
for file in $list
do
newf=`echo $file|cut -f1 -d'.'`
echo "The newf is $newf"
mv $file $newf.jpg
done

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `zsh` shell

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv '(**/)(*).txt' '$1$2.md'
```