# Changing a file extension using rename in OS X

Tags: linux, macos, unix, unix-timestamp

I have a lots of file names under a folder '/files' ,the extesnions of these files are appended with timestamp when that file was created,somthing like abc.csv_20170329. I want to change the extension of all these files to abc.csv_20170330 using the rename command in OSX using the terminal.Can any one help me with the exact command to do that i tried using 
$ rename -S  '*.csv_*'  .csv_20170330  '*.csv*'

but this does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing file extensions for all files in a directory OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887275/changing-file-extensions-for-all-files-in-a-directory-osx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 for file in abc.csv*
 do
    mv "$file" "$file__20170330"
 done
```